# Google Chrome and Firefox cache in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-cache

Where can I find the cache used by Google Chrome and Firefox in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 17):

Google Chrome

- Config path: `~/.config/google-chrome`
- Cache: `~/.cache/google-chrome`

Answer (score 10):

The location has changed in recent versions of Firefox.

- Firefox before 21:

  ```
  ~/.mozilla/firefox/[profile]/Cache
  ```
- For Firefox 21 or later, The location has moved to:

  ```
  ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/[profile]/Cache
  ```

Where `[profile]` is like `a_random_string.default` (any folder name which ends in `.default`, if you are using the default profile, separate profiles can have different folder names).

See bug report which brings the change: [Bug 239254 - [Linux] Support disk cache on a local path](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=239254)

Answer (score 4):

Normally in Ubuntu the cache folder for Firefox is located in:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/Cache
```

`<profile>` = `a_random_string.default` (any folder name which ends in `.default`, if you are using default profile, separate profile can have different folder names).

Comment: For chrome you can see if you have this folder or not /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/.cache/google-chrome/Cache

Comment: This answer is out of date as of Firefox 21.

Comment: @KevinPanko yes indeed, my answer is pretty old, look at Alvin's answer below which provides the new location for the cache folder since Firefox 21.

Answer (score -2):

It is in your home directory

```
ls -al ~
```

There will be a folder starting with '.'

```
.mozilla
```